# I want to auto populate data in three fields if one drop down is selected

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, dropdown

I just want to add auto populate in my WordPress plugin.
If i select a value in drop down menu then on that drop down value based i want my three fields are auto filled.

This is my js file code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#courname").change(function(){
    var courname = jQuery("#courname").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',   // Adding Post method
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url, // Including ajax file
        data: {
            action: "change_value", 
            "display": 2,
        }, 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(courname);
        }
});

});
});
```

These info add in wp_terms and wp_termmeta database table i want on selected course it would auto fill the three field.

These field i want to auto fill

```
<label>Price : </label>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="  "><br>
<label>Duration : </label>
<input type="text" id="duration" name="duration" value="">
<label>Maximum Capacity : </label>
<input type="text" id="mcap" name="mcap" value="">
```

Comment: Using jQuery may help you. We can't answer any thing more with the limited information available. Please elaborate the question.

Comment: i will edit my question see that .

Comment: what three fields? can you share the html also

Comment: i have added that code.